# Why setting date timezone by config() doesn't affect on date() result in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

The default timezone that is set in `config/app` file is `UTC` but for a short part of my project I want to change it to `Asia/Tehran`. I use config() function to set timezone value to what I want but it doesn't affecton date result.

please look to the below example:

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time()) . '<br>'; //here the current timezone is UTC
config(['app.timezone' => 'Asia/Tehran']); // I've set new timezone
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time()); //here the current timezone is Asia/Tehran
```

The above code result is same but they should be different.
Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

custom timezone config doesn't affect outputted date, try this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tehran');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that config changed at runtime will not take effect by the way why not to use Carbon

```
$timestamp = '2018-02-08 18:39:00';
$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp, 'Europe/Stockholm');
$date->setTimezone('UTC');
```